# Error: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I an getting an exception "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection" in the following code.Here in the code actually what going on is , handling some duplicate values which is finally occupying in a data grid

```
try
         {
            int index = alerts.Find(alertName);
            if (index >= 0 && tblAlarm.Rows.Count > idx)
            {
               DataRow row = tblAlarm.Rows[idx];
               m_dcDuplicates.ReadOnly = false;

            }
         }
```

Do i need to increase the size of types like `int` to `long` ? or any additional check in code is required ?

Comment: What line is throwing the error?  Where is m_dcDuplicates and dupValue assigned?

Comment: @Blam there is no line number, i updated my question with Find method and  my trace which i am getting

Comment: Is it some sort of threading is there?

Comment: @ponting, making a class thread-safe is hard; it's difficult to give advice without seeing the whole class.

Comment: @Joe since you asked i edited my question and put whole class code

Comment: @ponting - you need to use a lock statement when you're accessing elements in the collection too - e.g. in the indexer's getter.

Comment: @Joe sure i will use it there also, and one more modification i will do like i will replace List with InnerList,  will i?

Comment: @ponting, that's still not enough to make it completely thread-safe.  For example, a caller could attempt to iterate over the collection (foreach Alert alert in myArrayOfAlerts).  I'd advise you to reconsider your design - e.g. go for a design that avoids the need for a thread-safe collection.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a `lock` statement, this is presumably a multi-threaded implementation.

A likely cause is that you are failing to synchronize access to your object properly.  Look at any other code that updates the collection (`this` in your code above) - post it if the problem isn't obvious.

**UPDATE**

For example, in your updated source code, the indexer's setter is not synchronized:

```
public Alert this[int index]
{
    get ...
    set
    {
        this.List[index] = value;
    }
}
```

You probably need the following:

```
public Alert this[int index]
{
    get ...
    set
    {
        lock(this)
        {    
            this.List[index] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Another oddity in your code is that the `Add` and `Remove` methods reference `this.InnerList`, while the indexer references `this.List`.

Comment: hmm great, so do i need to do this.InnerList where indexer referencing going on. The problem now is severe, actually i am displaying all alerts in a datagrid which finally tuned in to a Big Red X window